# Good or bad:: Keeping large volume of documents in sitecore 8.1 Media Library

Tags: media-library

Do we have any limitation for documents( pdfs , excels , msword ) in media library in sitecore 8.1. Actually We are planning to upload around 60,000 documents in media library.

As I know the purpose of CMS is that we can full have control on content as per our need but sure not sure about this scenario

Comment: Do you have any requirements on the documents to put them in Sitecore? Any Sitecore feature that you need on them?

Comment: Please take a look at this post [Storing Sitecore media assets on the file system and how to get synced](https://buoctrenmay.wordpress.com/2017/03/25/storing-sitecore-media-assets-on-the-file-system-and-how-to-get-synced-at-your-machine/). Hopefully, you will have another option.

Comment: thanks Viet for your response on this...I'm going to figure out approach...this will help me alot...

Comment: @VietHoang please provide details on how this can help. This currently is a link only answer and does not provide enough detail. Please see [How to write a good answer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for detail.

Answer (score 7):

While Sitecore would be able to store that many documents, There are some things you may want to consider:

#### Maintenance

With the Search API in the content editor maintenance will be easier than it used to be, but still managing that amount of documents will not be simple.

**e.g** there is no way to bulk edit documents, or bulk move documents around. Sure you could use [Sitecore PowerShell Extentions](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_PowerShell_console.aspx) for that, but its still not the easiest.

#### Database Size

Another potential problem would be the size of the master and web DB's once you have that amount of documents in. This will make backup/restoring and general DB maintenance take longer, disk requirements will go up etc..

#### Publishing

Because you are on 8.1 the new publishing service is not available, so if you ever need to publish large parts of the media library, or worst case need to republish the entire site, this will take an extremely long time. Publishing media items is slower than normal items anyway because of the blob data.

With those considerations, if I were looking at storing that many documents and the budget allowed for it, I would look at a dedicated Digital Asset Management system (DAM) - Sitecore have [DAM for Sitecore](http://www.damforsitecore.com/) and there are others around. A dedicated DAM will solve a number of the above issues as they are built to manage that many documents.

If you have no budget for that, then Sitecore will be able to handle it, but plan the content tree carefully so you have the min amount of maintenance to do once the documents are there.

Comment: thanks richard for your response on this but as you mentioned `new publishing service is not available` what service you are talking about...

Comment: @Sukhi [Sitecore Publishing Service](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Publishing_Service/20/Sitecore_Publishing_Service_20_Initial_Release.aspx) is a new way of publishing that uses an external .net core process rather than running in the website process.

Comment: that's correct...I also have concern about `Database size/Publishing` and if budge allow I will definitely go for DAM other wise finally we will be ended up having lots of docs in media library node. 
Any suggestion on this I mean how should we plan keeping docs in media library in efficient way ( If business says NO for DAM )

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is not the number but the size that will drive your decision. Having a lot of blobs in your database means that you have to multiply this by 2 or 3 (master, web, public? database) + backups. Disk size consumption and restore time may be an issue.

Comment: yeah that's why looks like DAM implementation is best option